# Download файлов с сервера. Как получить файл в Andular 2 с сервера

Tags: java, angular2, typescript, download

Добрый вечер. Есть вопрос с которым совсем замучался.
Есть у меня бекенд на java, и в нем методы контроллера для upload/download файлов:
Upload:

```
`   @RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void continueFileUpload(@PathVariable("id") UUID id,
                                     @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){

        UploadFile newFile = new UploadFile();
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                newFile.setFile(file.getBytes());
                String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                newFile.setName(fileName);
                if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != 0) {
                    newFile.setType(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
                }
                newFile.setAssociatedProject(this.projectService.getById(id));
                uploadFileService.save(newFile);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Download:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fileDownload/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getDownloadFile(@PathVariable("id") UUID id,
                        HttpServletResponse response) {
    UploadFile uploadFile = this.uploadFileService.getById(id);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadFile.getFile());
    System.out.println("/*/**/"+ uploadFile.getFile().length);
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + uploadFile.getName().toString() + "\"");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(bis, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вот часть фронта (Angular 2) отвечающая за скачивание файла:

service:

```
      getMyFileFromBackend(file_id: string): Observable<any>{
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `${token}`);
    //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.get(this.entity_url + 'app/project/fileDownload/' + file_id, {headers} )
        .map((res:Response) => res.text())

      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));

  }
```

component:

```
  downloadFile(id: string, name: string, type: string){
    this.projectService.getMyFileFromBackend(id).subscribe(
      res => this.extractData(res, name, type),
      (error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error')
    );
  }

  extractData(res: string, name: string, type: string){
    let myBlob: Blob = new Blob([res],  {type: type }); // replace the type by whatever type is your response
    var a = document.createElement("a"),
      fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    //a.style = "display:none";
    a.type = type;
    a.href = fileURL;
    a.download = name;
    window.document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.document.body.removeChild(a);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
  }
```

ну и сама форма скачивания:

```
<td>
   <a class="bottom" (click)="downloadFile(file.id, file.name, file.type)">{{file.name}}</a>
</td>
```

Текстовые файлы скачиваются и открываются нормально, но все остальные, документы офиса, картинки и прочее, скачиваются но не открываются. Файлы битые и размер больше чем изначальный. Я подозреваю, что на фронте из ответа неправильно получаю файл, но самому найти проблему так и не получилось. Как решить проблему со скачиванием файлов?

Comment: Вы работаете с файлами как с текстом. `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");` и `.map((res:Response) => res.text())`. По идее если вы передаете бинарные файлы то должны правильно выставить content type и принять данные не как тескт. Посмотрите сюда еще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152917/get-image-or-byte-data-with-http

Comment: посмотрел пример, но непонятно откуда они берут res._body.

Comment: По идее должен использоваться метод arrayBuffer(): ArrayBuffer;
    /**
      * Returns the request's body as a Blob, assuming that body exists.
      */ но с ним та же беда.

Comment: а `res.blob()` тоже не сработает?

Comment: пробовал, не работает :(